# Is Poppy's Valiant Fighter applied on full damage or excess?

Tags: league-of-legends

Poppy's innate ability [Valiant Fighter](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Poppy_the_Iron_Ambassador#Valiant_Fighter) is as following:

> Any damage dealt to Poppy that exceeds 10% of her current health is
>   reduced by 50%. This does not reduce damage from structures.

But is the 50% reduction applied to the full damage or only the excess of the 10%?

In other words if Poppy took a hit that would do 12% of her total health in damage would it be reduced to 6% (12%/2) of her total health or 11%(10%+2%/2) of her total health?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some poking around [on the wiki you linked to](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Poppy_the_Iron_Ambassador/Ability_Details), and found my initial answer was wrong.

> Valiant Fighter is a passive ability that will activate whenever Poppy
>   takes damage that exceeds 10% of her current health, reducing that
>   damage by 50%.
>
> Valiant Fighter's damage reduction only applies to the
>   portion of the damage that actually exceeds 10% of Poppy's health, not
>   the entire damage.
>
> > For example: Poppy has 1200/2000 health and is
> >     being hit by a 400 damage nuke (after resistances). She will then
> >     take: 1200 × 10% regular damage plus (400-10% × 1200) × 50% reduced
> >     damage, which will total in 120+120=260 damage taken.
>
> Valiant
>   Fighter's damage reduction occurs after armor and magic resistance's
>   reduction.
>
> Valiant Fighter does not affect True damage.

Comment: So what you are trying to say is that it is on the full damage, not just excess of the 10%

Comment: @Blem No, I was wrong. Only the portion over 10% is reduced.

Comment: 120 + 120 = 260?